# Create heatmap in R on the entire matrix rather than by row

Tags: r

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYtgN.png)I want to create a heatmap in R which should consider formatting of colors by all the values in matrix and not just by rows. Ex: I've a following matix

```
row1 : 1,2,3,4
row2 : 50,50,50,50
```

When I use `heatmap()` to plot this matrix, I see row 1 with shades of color, however my `row2` is marked as white. I would rather want 50 to be rated in extreme color (eg: Red) and 1,2, 3 & 4 in lighter shades

Hope my question makes sense. Please let me know if anything is unclear. 
Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Akshat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read `?heatmap` carefully, you will see that by default the rows are scaled and **centered**.

```
row1 = c(1,2,3,4)
row2 = c(50,50,50,50)
m = t(as.matrix(cbind(row1, row2)))
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
heatmap(m, col=rev(heat.colors(15)))
heatmap(m, scale = "none", col=rev(heat.colors(15)))
```

Should do the trick.

[image]

#### Centered and Scaled (the default)

[image]

#### Edit: I reversed the color scale so that red maps to larger values.

2nd: Your desired output is going to be difficult to obtain because 50 is so much larger than the rest of your data. To regain the color detail in row1 you would need to set the `breaks` in the `heatmap` function until you get the desired result

```
heatmap(m, scale = "none", col=rev(heat.colors(5)), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,50))
```

[image]

Comment: very quick solution. Works fine! One question about the default behaviour. I understand scaled by row , but what does it mean by centered?

Comment: centering is subtraction of the row mean from each row element. So in your case the row of 50's all became 0 and thus white

Comment: Very insightful. Makes it very clear. Couple of more questions. How does breaks parameter work? by default the heatmap function gives the smaller value more darker shade?

Comment: Refer you to the help page for `heatmap` and `image` (called by heatmap) for the answers to those  questions

Comment: Sure. Will do. Thank you so much :) I am new to R and finding a good solution is a nice thing to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This function should work

```
library(plotly)
hmap <- function(mat, ... ) {
s <- 1:nrow(mat)
plot_ly(x = s, y = s, z = mat[rev(s), ], type = "heatmap", ...)
}

m <- matrix(1:8, 2, byrow = T)
hmap(m)
```

You can adjust colors with the `colors` argument, e.g.

```
hmap(m, colors = c('Red','Yellow','Green'))
```

Comment: This works exactly how i wanted. Little difficult for me to understand  the plot_ly function though. Can you please assist on color coding the heatmap here?

Comment: Thanks Jim, I used the colorRamp function in the plot_ly function itself, rather than passing it as a argument to hmap function. However, the color of the heatmap is not changing. One more question, Why did you use rev(). It works without rev() as well. Any specific reason?

Comment: Ironically, without `rev` the row order is reversed and with `rev` the rows are displayed in the same order as in the matrix.